# DFA languages & state diagrams

Tags: computation-theory, dfa, state-diagram

I am getting confused as a construct some state diagrams of the DFA, I am currently working through a problem with the constraint that `{w | w is any string not in a*b*}`. I do not understand what `a*b*` means exactly, can someone summarize that for me, thanks!

Comment: `*` is the Kleene closure. `x*` means `{ε, x, xx, xxx, xxxx, ...}`. `a*b*` therefore means `{ε, a, aa, aaa, ...}{ε, b, bb, bbb, ...}`.

Comment: In layman's terms * means zero or more of the preceding atom.  So a* could b null, a, aa, aaa, ... , and a*b* could be null, a, b, aa, bb, ab, ba, aaa, bbb, aab, abb, bba, baa, ...

Answer (score 0):

`a*b*`  means (zero or more a's followed by zero or more b's) .

Strings present in language `a*b*` are
L={epsilon(zero a's and zero b's) , a, b, ab, aab, abb...... }

DFA for strings in language `a*b*` are:

```
∆(q0, epsilon) = q0
∆(q0, a)       = q0
∆(q0, b)       = q1
∆(q1, b)       = q1
∆(q1, a)       = q2
∆(q2, a)       = q2
∆(q2, b)       = q2
```

Here, ∆ represents transition.
q0 is the initial state.
q0, q1 are final states.

Similarly DFA for strings not present in language `a*b*` are:

```
∆(q0, epsilon) = q0
∆(q0, a)       = q0
∆(q0, b)       = q1
∆(q1, b)       = q1
∆(q1, a)       = q2
∆(q2, a)       = q2
∆(q2, b)       = q2
```

Here, ∆ represents transition.
q0 is the initial state.
q2 is the final state.

Here is the image for above DFA's:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAt38.jpg  DFA image

Hope You Got it.!!